# Issue with Angular Translate

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angular-translate

I am having a span tag like below.

```
<span translate="footer.copyright">Copyright</span>
```

In my Json file I have data like below,

```
"footer": {
      "copyright": "Copyright ©"
    },
```

Its working fine too. But if the json file is not having the data, I want translate to show whatever content is available in between the span tag, in this case Copyright. But its not taking the content instead its showing empty tag. Please help me with this.

Comment: can you provide plunkr?

Comment: Please note that `<span translate="footer.copyright">` is invalid HTML. Use `<span data-translate="footer.copyright">` instead.

Comment: @connexo, this not matter in this case

Comment: Add `translate-default` to your tag, [reference](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/api/pascalprecht.translate.directive:translate)

Comment: @connexo: That depends on what HTML standard you're using.

Comment: @Ziki Thanks for you suggestion. ITs working fine. Please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just simply add `translate-default` to your tag:

```
<span translate="footer.copyright" translate-default="Copyright">Copyright</span>
```

You can read more [here](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/api/pascalprecht.translate.directive:translate).

Answer (score 0):

Use `translate-default` instead `translate`.

So your HTML look like

```
<span translate-default="footer.copyright">Copyright</span>
```

This would kind of sidestep the issue here, but then you'd end up with tags that look like

```
<ANY translate="missing.id" translate-default="This is some text"></ANY>
```

Where writing

```
<ANY translate="missing.id">This is some text</ANY>
```

Looks cleaner & simpler and would actually show the placeholder text in case of a JS error that prevents Angular/Angular-Translate from working, or when you open your view templates directly.

**NOTE:**
Keep in mind that the original situation where this problem occurred was, when the translation file was not loaded yet, for example due to slow internet connection. So at that point, Angular Translate would probably not know, yet, that it has to use the translate-default attribute for the content. Just try a custom `$missingTranslationHandlerFactory`.

Comment: `<ANY translate="translationKey">This is some text</ANY>` is what I use in my project... Kinda weird that it doesn't work for the OP...

Comment: This is just for example only. ANY means <div> <span>...etc

Comment: Yea, I figured as much. I'm just saying it's weird that that does not work for the OP.